# How to combine data in an array with duplicate identifier in the first column without removing duplicates in other columns

Tags: perl

I populated an array with tab delimited data. I would like to merge rows with duplicate ids in the first column without removing duplicates in other columns:

Here is what the lines of @fusions array look like before I run the code:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I’ve tried using a hash but it removes duplicates in all the columns and I need to remove duplicates in the first column only.
Here is the code I’ve adopted that uses a hash.

```
foreach (@fusions){
    chomp($_);
     my ($key, @items) = split /\t/;
     $fusion_hash{$key}{$_}++ for @items;
     }

#print join("\t", $_, sort keys %{$fusion_hash{$_}}), "\n" for sort keys %fusion_hash;
```

Please suggest how to change the code so it merges the data and doesn't remove duplicates in other columns. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of your data. Your data is text, so why not post it as text? I was just going to copy it into a test file so that I could work on your problem, but I have no intention of retyping the data, so I guess I'll help someone else instead.

Comment: Your absolut right, just couldnt resist to test http://www.onlineocr.net/ once ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the data in an array per "key"

```
use strict;
my %fusion_hash;
my @fusions= split("\n", <<EOT);
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R32.COSF1197 chr4 25665952 PASS 56812 SLC34A2 4 COSF1197 
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R32.COSF1197 chr6 117650609 PASS 56812 ROS1 32 COSF1197 
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R34.COSF1198 chr4 25665952 PASS 3367 SLC34A2 4 COSF1198 
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R34.COSF1198 chr6 117645578 PASS 3367 ROS1 34 COSF1198 
EOT

foreach (@fusions){
    chomp($_);
     my ($key, @items) = split /\s/;
     $fusion_hash{$key} = [] unless defined $fusion_hash{$key} ;
     push @{$fusion_hash{$key}}, @items;
}

#print join("\t", $_, @{$fusion_hash{$_}}), "\n" for sort keys %fusion_hash;
```

should do the job.

HTH
Georg

BTW: you can ommit the line

```
     $fusion_hash{$key} = [] unless defined $fusion_hash{$key} ;
```

as this is done by perl automatically.

Comment: What is the best way to dump this hash into an array for further processing? Thank you

Comment: I am not sure i understand you correctly, but maybe you are looking for  `push @result, join("\t", $_, @{$fusion_hash{$_}}) for sort keys %fusion_hash;` (If you define @ result before that)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different to Georg's answer. I only split the data into two parts (the bit we're matching on and the rest of the line).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  my ($key, $val) = split / /, $_, 2;
  push @{ $data{$key} }, $val;
}

foreach (sort keys %data) {
  say $_, "\t", join "\t", @{ $data{$_} };
}

__DATA__
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R32.COSF1197 chr4 25665952 PASS 56812 SLC34A2 4 COSF1197
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R32.COSF1197 chr6 117650609 PASS 56812 ROS1 32 COSF1197
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R34.COSF1198 chr4 25665952 PASS 3367 SLC34A2 4 COSF1198
SLC34A2-ROS1.S4R34.COSF1198 chr6 117645578 PASS 3367 ROS1 34 COSF1198
```

Comment: Could you please suggest how to push the merged  values from %data  into a  new array. Thanks

Comment: I could. But you're a programmer. It shouldn't be too hard for you to work it out yourself. You can see where the value is generated. Can't you just take that value and push it onto an array? If you can't manage that, then perhaps you should consider paying someone to do it for you.

Comment: I've tried `push (@final_array, $_, "\t", join "\t", @{ $fusion_hash{$_}});` but it’s not behaving as expected. when i try to split it by tab, just to test, It prints out the position twice and  the second time it's blank. `foreach `(@final_array){`
                 `chomp($_);`
                 
                `my @lineelementarray = split (/\t/, $_);`
                `my $position_1 = $lineelementarray[1];print "position is: `$position_1\n";`

Comment: @user3781528: You appear to be programming by trying things at random - and that's never a good idea. For a start, can you explain the difference between `$_, "\t", join "\t", @{ $data{$_} }` and `$_ . "\t" . join "\t", @{ $data{$_} }`? Do you know why you would choose one over the other? How many elements do you expect in `@final_array`? How many do you actually get?

Comment: "." is concatenation.. and this is what i need. thank you for your help.